# Android NoSuchMethod issue

Tags: android, testing, methods, proguard

I'm writing some tests and I'm getting an issue:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   primeId(Ljava/lang/String;)/boardingpass/BoardingPass$Builder;

I think it's from Proguard. I'm not sure how to make it work.
In my proguard file I said:

```
-keep class com.boardingpass.BoardingPass { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.boardingpass.BoardingPass.Builder { *; }
```

Here is the code for the BoardingPass class:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"PMD.ShortVariable", "checkstyle:finalclass"})
public class BoardingPass implements Parcelable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -687991496884005033L;

    public static final Creator<BoardingPass> CREATOR = new Creator<BoardingPass>() {
        @Override
        public BoardingPass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BoardingPass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BoardingPass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BoardingPass[size];
        }
    };

    public static final class Builder {
        private String primeId;
        private String qr;
        private byte[] qrCode;
        private String deck;
        private String aircraftType;
        private String airlineUse;
        private String departureGate;
        private String departureAirport;
        private String cabin;
        private String eTicketNumber;
        private String seatNumber;
        private String bookingReference;
        private String departureDate;
        private String scheduledArrivalTime;
        private String departureTerminal;
        private String offPoint;
        private String fullName;
        private String boardPoint;
        private boolean isA380;
        private String boardingDateTime;
        private String membershipNo;
        private String boardPointCode;
        private String flightNumber;
        private String boardingZone;
        private String scheduledDepartureTime;
        private String offPointCode;
        private String arrivalAirport;
        private String loungeText;
        private String operatingAirline;

        public Builder() {
        }

        public Builder primeId(String val) {
            primeId = val;
            return this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("PMD.ShortMethodName")
        public Builder qr(String val) {
            qr = val;
            return this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("PMD.ArrayIsStoredDirectly")
        public Builder qrCode(byte[] val) {
            qrCode = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder deck(String val) {
            deck = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder aircraftType(String val) {
            aircraftType = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder airlineUse(String val) {
            airlineUse = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder departureGate(String val) {
            departureGate = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder departureAirport(String val) {
            departureAirport = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder cabin(String val) {
            cabin = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder eTicketNumber(String val) {
            eTicketNumber = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder seatNumber(String val) {
            seatNumber = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder bookingReference(String val) {
            bookingReference = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder departureDate(String val) {
            departureDate = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder scheduledArrivalTime(String val) {
            scheduledArrivalTime = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder departureTerminal(String val) {
            departureTerminal = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder offPoint(String val) {
            offPoint = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder fullName(String val) {
            fullName = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder boardPoint(String val) {
            boardPoint = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder isA380(boolean val) {
            isA380 = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder boardingDateTime(String val) {
            boardingDateTime = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder membershipNo(String val) {
            membershipNo = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder boardPointCode(String val) {
            boardPointCode = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder flightNumber(String val) {
            flightNumber = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder boardingZone(String val) {
            boardingZone = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder scheduledDepartureTime(String val) {
            scheduledDepartureTime = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder offPointCode(String val) {
            offPointCode = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder arrivalAirport(String val) {
            arrivalAirport = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder loungeText(String val) {
            loungeText = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder operatingAirline(String val) {
            operatingAirline = val;
            return this;
        }

        public BoardingPass build() {
            return new BoardingPass(this);
        }
    }

    @SerializedName("primeId")
    private String primeId;

    @SerializedName("qrImage")
    private String qr;

    private transient byte[] qrCode;

    @SerializedName("deck")
    private String deck;

    @SerializedName("aircraftType")
    private String aircraftType;

    @SerializedName("airlineUse")
    private String airlineUse;

    @SerializedName("departureGate")
    private String departureGate;

    @SerializedName("departureAirport")
    private String departureAirport;

    @SerializedName("cabin")
    private String cabin;

    @SerializedName("eTicketNumber")
    private String eTicketNumber;

    @SerializedName("seatNumber")
    private String seatNumber;

    @SerializedName("bookingReference")
    private String bookingReference;

    @SerializedName("departureDate")
    private String departureDate;

    @SerializedName("scheduledArrivalTime")
    private String scheduledArrivalTime;

    @SerializedName("departureTerminal")
    private String departureTerminal;

    @SerializedName("offPoint")
    private String offPoint;

    @SerializedName("fullName")
    private String fullName;

    @SerializedName("boardPoint")
    private String boardPoint;

    @SerializedName("isA380")
    private boolean isA380;

    @SerializedName("boardingDateTime")
    private String boardingDateTime;

    @SerializedName("membershipNo")
    private String membershipNo;

    @SerializedName("boardPointCode")
    private String boardPointCode;

    @SerializedName("flightNumber")
    private String flightNumber;

    @SerializedName("boardingZone")
    private String boardingZone;

    @SerializedName("scheduledDepartureTime")
    private String scheduledDepartureTime;

    @SerializedName("offPointCode")
    private String offPointCode;

    @SerializedName("arrivalAirport")
    private String arrivalAirport;

    @SerializedName("loungeText")
    private String loungeText;

    @SerializedName("operatingAirline")
    private String operatingAirline;

    private BoardingPass(Parcel in) {
        primeId = in.readString();
        qr = in.readString();
        deck = in.readString();
        aircraftType = in.readString();
        airlineUse = in.readString();
        departureGate = in.readString();
        departureAirport = in.readString();
        cabin = in.readString();
        eTicketNumber = in.readString();
        seatNumber = in.readString();
        bookingReference = in.readString();
        departureDate = in.readString();
        scheduledArrivalTime = in.readString();
        departureTerminal = in.readString();
        offPoint = in.readString();
        fullName = in.readString();
        boardPoint = in.readString();
        isA380 = in.readByte() != 0;
        boardingDateTime = in.readString();
        membershipNo = in.readString();
        boardPointCode = in.readString();
        flightNumber = in.readString();
        boardingZone = in.readString();
        scheduledDepartureTime = in.readString();
        offPointCode = in.readString();
        arrivalAirport = in.readString();
        loungeText = in.readString();
        operatingAirline = in.readString();
    }

    private BoardingPass(Builder builder) {
        primeId = builder.primeId;
        qr = builder.qr;
        qrCode = builder.qrCode;
        deck = builder.deck;
        aircraftType = builder.aircraftType;
        airlineUse = builder.airlineUse;
        departureGate = builder.departureGate;
        departureAirport = builder.departureAirport;
        cabin = builder.cabin;
        eTicketNumber = builder.eTicketNumber;
        seatNumber = builder.seatNumber;
        bookingReference = builder.bookingReference;
        departureDate = builder.departureDate;
        scheduledArrivalTime = builder.scheduledArrivalTime;
        departureTerminal = builder.departureTerminal;
        offPoint = builder.offPoint;
        fullName = builder.fullName;
        boardPoint = builder.boardPoint;
        isA380 = builder.isA380;
        boardingDateTime = builder.boardingDateTime;
        membershipNo = builder.membershipNo;
        boardPointCode = builder.boardPointCode;
        flightNumber = builder.flightNumber;
        boardingZone = builder.boardingZone;
        scheduledDepartureTime = builder.scheduledDepartureTime;
        offPointCode = builder.offPointCode;
        arrivalAirport = builder.arrivalAirport;
        loungeText = builder.loungeText;
        operatingAirline = builder.operatingAirline;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(primeId);
        dest.writeString(qr);
        dest.writeString(deck);
        dest.writeString(aircraftType);
        dest.writeString(airlineUse);
        dest.writeString(departureGate);
        dest.writeString(departureAirport);
        dest.writeString(cabin);
        dest.writeString(eTicketNumber);
        dest.writeString(seatNumber);
        dest.writeString(bookingReference);
        dest.writeString(departureDate);
        dest.writeString(scheduledArrivalTime);
        dest.writeString(departureTerminal);
        dest.writeString(offPoint);
        dest.writeString(fullName);
        dest.writeString(boardPoint);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (isA380 ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeString(boardingDateTime);
        dest.writeString(membershipNo);
        dest.writeString(boardPointCode);
        dest.writeString(flightNumber);
        dest.writeString(boardingZone);
        dest.writeString(scheduledDepartureTime);
        dest.writeString(offPointCode);
        dest.writeString(arrivalAirport);
        dest.writeString(loungeText);
        dest.writeString(operatingAirline);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public byte[] getQrCode() {
        if (qrCode == null) {
            qrCode = Base64.decode(qr, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }

        return qrCode;
    }

    public String getPrimeId() {
        return primeId;
    }

    public String getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }

    public String getAircraftType() {
        return aircraftType;
    }

    public String getAirlineUse() {
        return airlineUse;
    }

    public String getDepartureGate() {
        return departureGate;
    }

    public String getDepartureAirport() {
        return departureAirport;
    }

    public String getCabin() {
        return cabin;
    }

    public String geteTicketNumber() {
        return eTicketNumber;
    }

    public String getSeatNumber() {
        return seatNumber;
    }

    public String getBookingReference() {
        return bookingReference;
    }

    public String getDepartureDate() {
        return departureDate;
    }

    public String getScheduledArrivalTime() {
        return scheduledArrivalTime;
    }

    public String getDepartureTerminal() {
        return departureTerminal;
    }

    public String getOffPoint() {
        return offPoint;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public String getBoardPoint() {
        return boardPoint;
    }

    public boolean isA380() {
        return isA380;
    }

    public String getBoardingDateTime() {
        return boardingDateTime;
    }

    public String getMembershipNo() {
        return membershipNo;
    }

    public String getBoardPointCode() {
        return boardPointCode;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public String getBoardingZone() {
        return boardingZone;
    }

    public String getScheduledDepartureTime() {
        return scheduledDepartureTime;
    }

    public String getOffPointCode() {
        return offPointCode;
    }

    public String getArrivalAirport() {
        return arrivalAirport;
    }

    public String getLoungeText() {
        return loungeText;
    }

    public String getOperatingAirline() {
        return operatingAirline;
    }

}
```

I thought that would keep the methods in, as I think what's happening is that the primeId in the builder is only used here so Proguard might strip it out?

Appreciate any help with it

Comment: Please post the code for your `BoardingPass` class as well as the code which uses the `primeId()` method.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My bad. Fixed now

Comment: Builder seems like a redundant class, you could just be using BoardingPass (or am I looking at something wrong). Not really a solution to the problem, just wondering :P

Comment: @zgc7009 Nah I'm using it to create a boarding pass to mock it for testing, not sure how I can provide stuff to it otherwise

Comment: BoardingPass would just need a default constructor and some setter methods (just like you are doing with the Builder class), you just wouldn't need a return value. That being said, make sure that everything you have is up to date in regards to versions, builds, etc., seems like maybe a library and your code have incompatible code somewhere or something.

Comment: @zgc7009 nah i need to use a builder as the senior dev asked me to. as far as i know its all up to date